# find speedup for different number of processes

Tags: python, classification, efficiency, c++, hpc

I am new to data science
I need to create code to find speedup compared with the number of processes while using a k-nearest neighbor. which (k=1,2,3,4,5,6,7).
this process should be after downloading some datasets.
it is preferred to use python.

What is the appropriate code in python for that?

Comment: I don't understand: you want to distribute the processes for different values of k? If so what is the difficulty?

Comment: What is the appropriate code in python?

Comment: you can find many tutorials online about threading, for instance https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/. Another option is to run a regular python program multiple times in parallel, either by calling it in a script or manually.